# Some problems of conversion of xacro to urdf

Tags: ros, urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,everyone.
I'm reading the book《mastering ros robotics programming》,and in chapter 2 I'm meeting some problems when I try to convert the xacro file to urdf file in the demo "seven_dof_arm".

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 & Ros Kinetic.

The xacro file and it's incluing sensor file are downloaded from https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/tree/master/chapter_2_codes/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/urdf

When I run the command `rosrun xacro xacro.py seven_dof_arm.xacro > seven_dof_arm.urdf` ，

the terminal shows:

```
xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
old: http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro1
new: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro1 (/home/dd/catkin_workspace/src/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/urdf/sensors/xtion_pro_live.urdf.xacro)
deprecated: xacro tags should be prepended with 'xacro' xml namespace.
Use the following script to fix incorrect usage:
find . -iname "*.xacro" | xargs sed -i 's#<([/]\?)(if\|unless\|include\|arg\|property\|macro\|insert_block)#<\1xacro:\2#g'
when processing file: seven_dof_arm.xacro

unknown macro name: xacro:base
XacroException(u'unknown macro name: xacro:base',)
when processing file: seven_dof_arm.xacro
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259511/some-problems-of-conversion-of-xacro-to-urdf/) by [cloud1980_cn](https://answers.ros.org/users/30068/cloud1980_cn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The xacro macro `base` is not defined in that xacro file nor in any file that it includes. I did a quick search of the source in that repository and I couldn't find a macro named `base` defined anywhere. I don't have the book you mentioned, but perhaps it instructs you to use a package from somewhere else that defines that macro? Even if it does, the `seven_dof_arm.xacro` file would need to include the file defining the `base` macro for it to work.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1